# Coded country names

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, pattern

Study the following table and answer the question given at the end.

| Code | Country |
| --- | --- |
| (0100,10) | Estonia |
| (0100,010) | Andorra |
| (0100,1) | Malta |
| (0100,1100) | Congo |
| (010,000) | Saint Kitts and Nevis |

---

***Which country will have the code (01,01) according to the table?***

Comment: Binary for these is (4,2), (4,2), (4,12), (2,0) but together is 18, 34, 9, 76, and 16. Country codes unlikely here…

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are

> Morse code representations of the double letters in the countries' capitals, where 0 is a dot and 1 is a dash:
>
>  0100 10 = `.-.. -.` = `LN`: Ta**ll**i**nn**, Estonia
>  0100 010 = `.-.. .-.` = `LR`: Ando**rr**a De La Ve**ll**a, Andorra
>  0100 1 = `.-.. .` = `LT`: Va**ll**e**tt**a, Malta
>  0100 1100 = `.-.. --..` = `LZ`: Bra**zz**avi**ll**e, Congo
>  010 000 = `.-. ...` = `RS`: Ba**ss**ete**rr**e, Saint Kitts and Nevis
>
>  So,
>  01 01 = `.- .-` = `AA`: Ul**aa**nb**aa**tar, **Mongolia**.

Comment: wow how does one to come think of this?

Comment: @kopaka The sequences of 0s and 1s seemed like they weren't binary numbers, since they could start with 0. So I tried to think of other sorts of codes they could be -- and there's one code I know with sequences of two symbols, with length 1 to 4...

After all of them seemed to decode correctly (I didn't hit any non-Morse letters), I looked for anything associated with Congo that had a Z in it, and from there it was simple.